# Node js access variable inside async function

Tags: jquery, node.js, json

I have the  following function :

```
module.exports = {
    PDF_Function: function (url) {

        (async () => {
            console.log("Our URL => "+url);
            const url = 'http://localhost:81/site/products/travel/mpdf';
            const buffer = await Webpage.generatePDF(url);
           return '1';
        })();

    }
};
```

How can I access the  URL value from   `PDF_Function: function (url)`  inside the  async function, when I tried to console it I get the following error =>

```
(node:66420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'url' before initialization
```

Comment: @Adam Agreed, finding the right dupe. Let me fix that.

Comment: @Adam Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should **avoid same variable names**:

```
module.exports = {
        PDF_Function: function (urlAsArgument) {

            (async () => {
                console.log("Our URL => "+ urlAsArgument);
                const url = 'http://localhost:81/site/products/travel/mpdf';
                const buffer = await Webpage.generatePDF(url);
               return '1';
            })();

        }
    };
```

Your argument name in `PDF_Function` and a `const` name inside your `async` function were same.

I hope it will help.

Comment: What's the change you have done?

Comment: Ah great find... 

Comment: The `argument` name and the `const` name (url) both were same.

Comment: Yep, noticed it.